# Issue in parsing the data received on MSCOM event in vb6

Tags: vb6, serial-port, at-command

I am working with the GSM modem. I am getting data on port with particular syntax for RING and Message like for ring

```
RING+CLIP: "+919860939518",145,"",,"",0
```

and for message

```
+CMT: "BP-bytwoo",,"14/08/02,13:16:41+22 9860939518:hello6
```

I have created a hyper terminal in Textbox1, getting data of text1 in text3. Then Storing data in a variable called `str`. Then looking for string `RING` and `+CMT` in the data extracted from text3 using `str_1 = Mid(Text3, 1, 6)` and display in text4.

I am able to extract words `RING` and `+CMT`. Then I check that if data extracted is equal to `RING` then extract the number and display it in textbox2, or if data extracted is equal to `+CMT` then display the data in text box 5.

But even though string `RING` and `+CMT` are extracted successfully, I am not able to retrieve the phone numbers which has to be displayed in textbox2 and textbox5. These text boxes shows absolutely nothing. I don't understand why it is happening. Please guide me. Here is my code.

```
  Dim str As String 
  Dim val As Integer
  Dim str_1 As String

  Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


  Private Sub Form_Load()
  'On Error GoTo errx:
  Dim strValue As String '  define Buffer value from Modem
              If MSComm1.PortOpen = True Then MSComm1.PortOpen = False
                 MSComm1.CommPort = 6   'comm port no.   
                 MSComm1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
                 MSComm1.RThreshold = 1    'no. of chr to receive
                 MSComm1.SThreshold = 1
                 MSComm1.InputLen = 0  '  no. of chr on which oncomm  event fires  
                'MSComm1.RTSEnable = True
                'MSComm1.InputMode = comInputModeText
                 MSComm1.PortOpen = True  'open comm port
                 MSComm1.Output = "AT + CLIP = 1" + Chr(13)
                 Sleep 1000 
                'MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" + Chr(13) '& Chr(10)
                'Sleep 500
                 MSComm1.Output = "AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0" + Chr(13) '1,2,0,0,0
                 Sleep 1000
               End If
 'errx:
  ' MsgBox "error"

  End Sub

  Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
  Static Buffer As String

  t = Now() + timeout / 86400000#


          If MSComm1.CommEvent = comEvReceive Then
             Do
               Text1 = Text1 + MSComm1.Input
               If Now() > t Then Exit Do
             Loop
             Text3 = Text1
             Text1 = ""
          End If


  str = Text3
  str_1 = Mid(Text3, 1, 6)
  Text4 = str_1

          If (str_1 = "RING") Then
              Text2.Text = Mid(str_1, 19, 13)  'Left$(str_1, 15) 

          ElseIf (str_1 = "+CMT") Then                  
              Text5.Text = Mid(str_1, 19, 13)   '19,13
          Else
              Exit Sub
          End If


  MSComm1.InBufferCount = 0

  End Sub
```

Compiler not even going in loop `If(str_1="RING") Then`. Why is it so.

Comment: What is your current code, and which parts are you have problems with now?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have:

```
str = Text3
str_1 = Mid(Text3, 1, 6)
Text4 = str_1

If (str_1 = "RING") Then
   Text2.Text = Mid(str_1, 19, 13)  'Left$(str_1, 15) 
ElseIf (str_1 = "+CMT") Then                  
   Text5.Text = Mid(str_1, 19, 13)   '19,13
Else
   Exit Sub
End If
```

The problem is that you try to get **Mid$(str_1, 19, 13)**, when **str_1** is either "RING" or "+CMT" (i.e. there is never more than 4 chars). Instead, use **str** as in **Mid$(str, 19, 13)**. That should do it.

Also, to make sure your If/Else clauses actually work, and if your intention is really to look at the characters 3 to 6 inclusively (and not 6 chars), then instead of

```
str = Text3
str_1 = Mid(Text3, 1, 6)
Text4 = str_1
```

you should have something like

```
str = Text3.Text
str_1 = Mid$(str, 3, 4)
Text4.Text = str_1
```

You'll see I also made style corrections:

- Don't rely on default properties, write them out instead (more legible, so someone can actually see at first glance that Text4 isn't a variable or property, but an object)
- Use strongly typed string versions of Mid(), Left(), etc., which are Mid$(), Left$(), and so on.

**EDIT:**

With everything from above, you code after grabbing the input into Text3 should look like:

```
str = Text3.Text
str_1 = Mid$(str, 3, 4)
Text4.Text = str_1

If (str_1 = "RING") Then
   Text2.Text = Mid$(str, 19, 13) ' provided index 19 is still valid
ElseIf (str_1 = "+CMT") Then                  
   Text5.Text = Mid$(str, 19, 13) ' provided index 19 is still valid
Else
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thanx John. Issue with the str_1 was due to copy pasting, i resolved that already. As you suggested i used Left$, but with that the original string i want to get is also getting truncated to RING, then using Left$(Text3.text,4) I am getting only two letters, RI. But if i use Left$(Text3.text,6) then I am getting RING or +CMT completely. After that too, IF-Else condition is failing. I am checking a simple string whether it is present or not, and extracting the corresponding string, but that too is not working. I wonder why If-Else condition is failing.

Comment: i used Trim,no use. Testpos = InStr(1, Text3, "RING")
Text7 = Testpos        ''''''-----------------------> Testpos number is 3<---------------------------   
If (Testpos <> 0) Then
str = Trim$(Text3)
'str_1 = Mid(Text3, 1, 6)
str_1 = Left$(str, 6)
Text4 = str_1
        
            If (str_1 = "RING") Then
                'str = Left$(str, 19)  'Left$(str_1, 15) '-----------22,10------------
                Text3 = Trim$(Text3)
                str = Mid$(Text3, 19, 13)
                Text2 = str
                  
            End If
        
End If

Comment: You have two options: 1) you must either find out what those first two chars are (i.e. before "RING" and "+CMT") and devise a function that will left-trim your input from those; or 2) always discard the first two chars from the modem input. I've updated the answer with regards to option 2 (i.e. taking chars #3 to #6 of text in Text3)